# Read data from glue catalog in AWS Glue Job

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have glue job which is connected to Kafka.Data is saved in Glue Data Catalog and in job I need to read it.I tried next:

```
df = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(database = "t-kafka-db", table_name = "t-kafka", transformation_ctx = "df", connectionType="kafka")
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(database="t-kafka-db",table_name="t-kafka",transformation_ctx="df")
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "t-kafka-db",table_name = "t-kafka",transformation_ctx = "df",additional_options = {"startingOffsets": "earliest", "inferSchema": "false"})
```

All of them returns same error:

`An error occurred while calling o67.getCatalogSource. We don't support this connection type: KAFKA`

Help to solve it

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue now supports reading from Kafka. Please refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-streaming.html#create-table-streaming) which talks about Creating a Data Catalog Table for a Streaming Source.